# How to check if the date comes in between the particular date range in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In my requirement, I am inserting the residential history details into the GridView... 
It also contains FromDate & ToDate... So for first row, there is no condition..
On inserting second row, the FromDate & ToDate should not clash with my first row date range.. 
Is there any idea to avoid that????

FromDate       ToDate          Place

12/10/2012     12/05/2013      XXXXX

12/05/2004     12/09/2014      YYYYY

Second row should not be Allowed.. Bcoz in 2004 - 2014, already 2012 - 2013 time period is already mentioned.. So, this thing should not be added into the GridView

My Code:

```
protected bool ValidateResidenceDates(DateTime frmDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["ResidenceNew"];

        if(dt != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    DateTime dtFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["HKR_FromDate"], ci);
                    DateTime dtToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["HKR_ToDate"], ci);

                    if (frmDate > dtFromDate && frmDate < dtToDate)
                    {
                        Com.MessageBox("From Date is Already Mentioned in the Residence History Date Range", UpdatePanel1);
                        SetFocus(txtResideFromDate);
                        isValid = false;
                        return isValid;
                    }
                    if (toDate > dtFromDate && toDate < dtToDate)
                    {
                        Com.MessageBox("To Date is Already Mentioned in the Residence History Date Range", UpdatePanel1);
                        SetFocus(txtResideToDate);
                        isValid = false;
                        return isValid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: while inserting compare the fromdate and todate with firstrow date range

Comment: I already tried that.. but that is not working

Comment: please post the code you are using to check and insert the row

Comment: the above mentioned scenario, is not working for your idea...

Comment: what you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: @ManikandanK well perhaps you are doing something wrong, post what you have tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: The best idea would be to test it... comparing dates is not much more difficult than comparing numbers, you should try and come here with some code if you get stuck. Don't expect a correct and accurate answer with such a bad question... you 'll end up losing your time and ours.

Comment: i want to create a daterange of the two dates.. how to create it??

Comment: @BenRobinson is there any idea to create daterange???

Comment: What do you actually want to do, I assumed you wanted to filter out the unwanted rows. The code you have posted looks like it would display a message and set the focus on a particular control as soon as it found an invalid date.

Comment: i want to restrict the user, not to add invalid or repeated date ranges..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check following scenario:

1) frmDate >= dtFromDate && toDate <= dtToDate

Let say there is already entry for 2003-2015 then user can not add 2004-2014

2) frmDate <= dtFromDate && toDate >= dtToDate

this is the case which you have mentioned. already added for 2012-2013 then user can not add 2004-2014